# I wanted to know if there is a function like this (python)

Tags: python, function

I wanted to know if there is a function like that can choose from some values randomly
like if i give the function these values 837,475,253,585 it will choose one randomely like if it chooses 253 randomely i wanted to know if there is a function like that i searched on google but it didnt show me much (BTW I AM TALKING ABOUT PYTHON)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use random library and use the choice option and set those values as options

```
import random

mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

print(random.choice(mylist))
```

Comment: `random` is a builtin module in pyhton, you don't need to install it.

Comment: Oops, my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

There is such a function as mentioned here - random.choice(). It is built-in Python library
We have an numpy alternative, which is more optimized for these types of operations. It need to be installed by `pip install numpy`

```
import numpy as np
rand_choice = np.random.choice(a = 5, size = 5, replace = True, p = weights)
```